# Plone 4 Zope Display Contents of specific folder TALES

Tags: plone, template-tal, zpt

### Problem

I have a customer that wishes to display the entire contents of a certain folder (containing images) on their search page, should the search return 0 results. The folder is located at mysite.com/images

### Setup:

As a test environment I have setup a seperate site with the following structure:

```
ROOT
|-Folder1 <-- current directory I am viewing
| |-images
|-Other folders
```

I modified the `folder_summar_view` template, to include the following code (I decided to modify a view to see if I could hack that to pieces to make it do what I want):

```
<div tal:define="image context/images/getFolderContents">
  <div tal:content="i" tal:repeat="i image" />
</div>
```

### What I see:

```
<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0x9d2ddb8>
```

### Things I've tried and further explanations

I was under the assumption that when the `context/images/getFolderContents` returns a brain for the 'objects' in my images folder, I could then iterate through each 'object' using my `tal:repeat` statement below it. Then display them on my page.

If I just use the following code:

```
<div tal:content="context/images/getFolderContents" />
```

My output is very similar to the above 'What I see' section:

```
<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at [...]>
```

*where [...] is another number*

I've been doing some research and reading the Plone Theming book, but my code is similar to their `tal:repeat` examples on **page 169**, it seems the only difference is they are not using this on a brain (as far as I can tell).

I tried this, although it produced the same results (not sure why I tought it wouldn't):

```
<div tal:define="image python:context.images.getFolderContents()">
  <div tal:content="i" tal:repeat="i image" />
</div>
```

I don't seem to be able to 'get inside' the returned brain. Everything I've looked for online doesn't quite help that much, I've also trawled through the `atct_album_view` and `folder_listings` templates to know avail. - I think I'm overlooking or missing something.

[The first link I stumbled across was this](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/CustomizeFolderViews), however I have moved on since that as although similar, it's not quite what I was trying to do.

The Plone guys on their chat room were kind enough to give me the `context/images/getFolderContents` statement, I tried to press on without asking for help again but it seems I've hit a wall.

### More stuff I've tried

[Using this link as inspiration](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/wiki/TAL) I decided to try the following:

```
<div tal:define="image context/images/getFolderContents">
  <div tal:content="image/getURL" />
</div>
```

But that throws an error when I try to view the template. The error reads along the lines of the 'getFolderContents brain does not have the attribute getURL' - Although `image/Title` displays the name of the folder, but that's not really what I need.

[I also found this link](http://developer.plone.org/searching_and_indexing/query.html) however because I am making use of the default search, I don't really want to have to edit python scripts as I fear it may adversely effect the normal Plone site search. [Also in this link](http://developer.plone.org/content/listing.html) they seem to be making use of more Python scripts. - To expand on this point, I'm not sure on how these scripts 'link' with page templates (how they know to 'talk' to one another).

### Conclusion

In conclusion I need to display all of the images contained within a folder named "images" located at the root of my site, I am unable to access the contents of a returned brain using `getFolderContents`. And other than displaying the title of the "images" folder or the brain identifcation (`<Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains object at 0x9d2ddb8>`) , I have had no luck. Any help or ideas welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As getFoldercontents returns a list of brains i cant see how your code can work.
Just repeat over it with something like that :

```
<tal:block tal:repeat="image context/images/getFolderContents">
  <a tal:attributes="href image/getURL" tal:content="image/Title"/>
</tal:block>
```